# Can we see a "mod note" on flag history for when the user's account was deleted?

Tags: feature-request, flags, flag-history

I'm loving the new flag history page. Ah, the memories of all that spam...

There are a number of cases where the flagged content was deleted because the entire account was deleted (as happens often with pure spammer accounts). Normally you would see "post deleted", but in these cases you see nothing. It would be helpful to see something like "account deleted" or "spammer murdered; body dumped".

Comment: Could you post a link to the "new flag history page" for completness?

Comment: @Wether - `http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-weight/{your user id}`